# Empty Statement in Try Except

Tags: nim-lang

I'm sure that there is an answer to this, but I haven't found it yet. In C# I would put a semicolon, followed by a comment. What's the equivalent in nim? How do I say - Okay that threw an exception, but I don't care, do nothing. I don't want to write an echo :)

```
try:
  var a = x + y + N /10
except:
  echo "what's the best way to make this an empty statement?"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `discard` statement:

```
try:
    var a = x + y + N / 10
except:
    discard
```